# Fetch the line in a file that mention specific keywords

Tags: python, pandas

I have two files, **keywords_file** (5MB) contain one word per line.Here's a sample :

```
prénom
pseudonyme
surnom
accès aux origines
puissance paternelle
droit de l’enfant
devoir de protection
droit à la survie
travail des enfants
obligation scolaire
assistance éducative
mauvais traitements
filiation adultérine
```

**r_isa** (205MB) that contain words that share an "isa" relationship. Here's a sample, where `\t` represents a literal tab character:

```
égalité de Parseval\tformule_0.9333\tégalité_1.0
filiation illégitime\tfiliation_1.0
Loi reconnaissant l'égalité\tloi_1.0
égalité entre les sexes\tégalité_1.0
liberté égalité fraternité\tliberté_1.0
```

This means, "égalité de Parseval" isa "formule" with a score of 0.9333 and isa "égalité" with a score of 1. And so go on..

I want to fetch from the r_isa file, the words that have the hypernym relationship with the keywords mentioned on the keywords_file. Here's what I did:

```
keywords = pd.read_csv("keywords_file.txt", sep="\t",encoding = 'utf8', header=None)
with open("r_isa.txt",encoding="utf-8") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for k in keywords[0]:
            if k in line:
                file = open('isa.txt','a', encoding='utf-8')
                file.write(("".join(line) + "\n"))
                file.close()
```

This keeps running no stop through the entire night. I'm guessing something must be wrong. Any help?

PS: i wanted to add a regular expression like this :

```
...
    for k in keywords[0]:
        if re.search(r'\b' + k + r'\b', line):
...
```

to look up for the exact word on each line but that threw me the following error so i left it as it is now:

```
error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 69
```

Comment: I should look for all the keyword "travail des enfants", that is why i called it keyword and not simply word. It's like The White House, the three words form one meaning

Comment: And the expected output is that any line which contains exactly `travail des enfants` in the first field (exactly? or as a substring?) should be appended to the output file, is that correct?  The whole line from `r_isa.txt`?

Comment: Yes the ideal would be that each time `travail des enfants` is the first field ( like `travail des enfants\t travail_0.5\t enfant_0.3`), the whole line should be appended to the ouput file ( one result of a keyword each line). I'm running the code of your answer and it's still running, the final file is created but nothing is being written on it. I will try again with only a sample just to see if it works

Comment: Oh, the regex error suggests that some of your keywords contain regex metacharacters; try `re.escape(k)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the main bottleneck is the repeated opening for appending inside the tight loop. The operating system will need to open the file and seek to the end every time you write to it.  If you need several writers to have access to the end of the file, maybe run each of them with output to a separate file, then combine the result files when all the writers are done.

I'm also a bit suspicious about the order in which you read the files. Apparently the raw `r_isa.txt` file is bigger, but if it contains fewer lines than the `keywords.txt` file, perhaps switch them.  Generally, try to read the smaller set of data into memory, then loop over the bigger file, one line at a time.

Here's an attempt completely without Pandas.  There's probably nothing wrong with using it, but it also doesn't really provide much value here.

I also switched to using a regex; it's not clear to me whether that's going to be a performance improvement, but at least it should show you how to get this going so you can measure and compare.

```py
import re

keywords = []
with open("keywords_file.txt") as kwfile:
    keywords = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in kwfile]

regex = re.compile(r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(keywords) + r')\b')

with open("r_isa.txt") as readfile, open('isa.txt', 'w') as writefile:
    for line in readfile:
        firstfield = line.split('\t')[0]
        m = regex.match(firstfield)
        if m:
            writefile.write(line)
```

Regular expressions are good for looking for substring matches and variations; if you simply want every line where *exactly* the first field exists verbatim as a line in the keywords file, this is almost certainly going to be quicker:

```py
    for line in readfile:
        firstfield = line.split('\t')[0]
        if firstfield in keywords:
            writefile.write(line)
```

and then of course take out `import re` and the `regex` assignment.  Maybe also then convert `keywords` to a `set()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but nothing is being written on the file..

Comment: Your files would not happen to have DOS line endings, would they?

Comment: Should the phrases be normalized to all lower case, by the way?

Comment: Indeed that was the catch! thank you so much for your help it works now :) ( at least for the sample)

Comment: I updated the ideone link to demonstrate how to use a set instead of a list. The change is very simple, but rather subtle; switch to curly braces in the comprehension.